# What is the reason for the bug in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, n-queens

I tried this python code for n-queens problem and I am not getting any output.
Could someone tell me where I have gone wrong?

```
def initialize(n):
    for key in ['queen','row','col','nwtose','swtone']:
       board[key]={}
    for i in range(n):
       board['queen'][i]=-1
       board['row'][i]=0
       board['col'][i]=0
    for i in range(-(n-1),n):
       board['nwtose'][i]=0
    for i in range(2*n-1):
       board['swtone'][i]=0
def printboard():
   for row in sorted(board['queen'].keys()):
      print((row,board['queen'][row]))
def free(i,j):
   return(board['row'][i]==0 and board['col'][j]==0 and board['nwtose'][j-i]==0 and board['swtone'][j+i]==0)
def addqueen(i,j):
   board['queen'][i]=j
   board['row'][i]=1
   board['col'][j]=1
   board['nwtose'][j-i]=1
   board['swtone'][j+i]=1
def undoqueen(i,j):
   board['queen'][i]=-1
   board['row'][i]=0
   board['col'][j]=0
   board['nwtose'][j-i]=0
   board['swtone'][j+i]=0
def placequeen(i):
   n=len(board['queen'].keys())
   for j in range(n):
      if free(i,j):
         addqueen(i,j)
         if i==n-1:
            return(True)
         else:
            extendsoln=placequeen(i+1)
         if extendsoln:
            return(True)
         else:
            undoqueen(i,j)
     else:
        return(False)
board={}
n=int(input("How many queens?"))
initialize(n)
if placequeen(0):
       printboard()
```

The print statement in printboard() function is not working. Could anyone help me with reasoning why?

Comment: WDYM the print is not working? What do you see, what do you expect, what happens?

Comment: `placequeen(0)` will return `None` and `None` is treated as `False` in if statements meaning `printboard()` is never called.

Comment: You haven't returned any thing from function `initialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

Copied and ran your code and got the following error:

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

It's talking about the last 'else-statement' in your placequeeen function

Copie this and try again please:

```
def placequeen(i):
   n=len(board['queen'].keys())
   for j in range(n):
      if free(i,j):
         addqueen(i,j)
         if i==n-1:
            return(True)
         else:
            extendsoln=placequeen(i+1)
         if extendsoln:
            return(True)
         else:
            undoqueen(i,j)
      else: # << this needed a space
        return(False)
```

What editor/IDE are you using? I recommend using pycharm, it gave me this error before i had to ran the code.

Let me know if this solved your problem!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the problem was not an external error. The code executes perfectly fine but it's just that it isn't printing anything

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not printing anything is because your if-statement executes as False, while you expect it to be True.

*Checkout for your self with this code (added an else-block to catch the output if statement is False):*

```
board={}
n=int(input("How many queens?"))
initialize(n)
if placequeen(0):
    print("Output == True")
    printboard()
else: #<< added for debug purposes
    print("Output == False")
    printboard()
```

**Cause & Solution**

The reason why your conditional executes as False might be because in your placequeen() function you use the 'Return' statements inside the for-loop.

You need to debug this function() and check why it (almost) allways returns noting (=False).

The rootcause of your issue lies within the placequeen() function. Hopefully this will set you on the right path to fixing it!

Comment: By the way: when you input 1 into the prompt, it executes as True!